# Reading date columns from Excel

Tags: c#, npoi

I am trying to read date cell from Excel file:

```
private string GetDateValueFromRowOrNull(ISheet worksheet, int row, int column, StringBuilder exceptionMessage, CellType? cellType = null)
{
    var cell = worksheet.GetRow(row).GetCell(column);
    if (cell == null)
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }

    if (cellType != null)
    {
        cell.SetCellType(cellType.Value);
    }

    var cellValue = worksheet.GetRow(row).GetCell(column).DateCellValue;

    if (cellValue != null)
    {
        return cellValue;
    }

    return String.Empty;
}
```

But I am getting an error while trying to return the `cellValue`:

> Can not implicitly convert type System.DateTime to string

```
if (cellValue != null)
{
    return cellValue;
}
```

I am using NPOI for the Excel functions.

Comment: Why not return a date instead of string?

Comment: When you return CellValue, this has a DateTime format. You need to write << return CellValue.ToString(); >> in order to provide a string as return format of your method.

Answer (score 4):

You can read the datetime value as string from excel then convert it to a DateTime object.

Sample converter code:

```
public static DateTime GetDateTime(string day, string month, string year)
{
    try
    {
        return Convert.ToDateTime(string.Format("{0} {1}, {2}", (object)day, (object)month, (object)year));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Comment: The value is already a DateTime (`worksheet.GetRow(row).GetCell(column).DateCellValue;`). There is no need to do this. The issue is that OP needs to decide if a string is needed or a DateTime is needed.

Comment: I removed the following code: `return String.Empty;`

Answer (score 0):

I have sorted it. @Fredy’s comment was right.

```
var cellValue = worksheet.GetRow(row).GetCell(column).DateCellValue;

    if (cellValue != null)
    {
        return cellValue.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you require a `DateTime` to be returned from your method you need to change the method signature to return `DateTime` instead of `string`. Given the possibility of a null value, I also suggest you actually return a nullable date and make sure callers of this method handle nulls the same way you were expecting them to handle empty string:

```
private DateTime? GetDateValueFromRowOrNull(ISheet worksheet, int row, int column, StringBuilder exceptionMessage, CellType? cellType = null)
{
    var cell = worksheet.GetRow(row).GetCell(column);
    if (cell == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    if (cellType != null)
    {
        cell.SetCellType(cellType.Value);
    }

    var cellValue = worksheet.GetRow(row).GetCell(column).DateCellValue;

    if (cellValue != null)
    {
        return cellValue;
    }

    return null;
}
```